# Restangular how to build custom url

Tags: angularjs, restangular

with this code

```
RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:8080/api/1');
var elements = Restangular.all('events');
elements.getList();
```

I can call the endpoint

> http://localhost:8080/api/1/events

but how can manage the code to have

> http://localhost:8080/api/1/events/around/me

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code, to get the events

```
var getEvents = Restangular.oneUrl('getEventAroundMe', 'http://localhost:8080/api/1/events/around/me');
```